# Index out of bounds, but not?

Tags: java, android

I have no idea how this is happening, maybe I'm missing something simple.

I am trying to remove the first index if it exists with code like this:

```
ArrayList<String> historyValues = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> historyLabels = new ArrayList<String>();
some_big_process_which_populates_array()
if(historyLabels.size() >= 1 && historyValues.size() >= 1 ){
    historyLabels.add("Not enough data yet");
    historyValues.add("0.0");
}else{
    Log.v("history_values", historyValues.toString());
    historyValues.remove(0);
    historyLabels.remove(0);
}
```

And the error. How is the empty array getting past the `size()` checks?

```
    06-18 15:36:53.208  1510815108/com.rainforestautomation.android.energyvue V/history_values﹕ []
06-18 15:36:53.208  15108-15108/com.rainforestautomation.android.energyvue D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-18 15:36:53.209  15108-15108/com.rainforestautomation.android.energyvue E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.rainforestautomation.android.energyvue, PID: 15108
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
```

EDIT:

It appears I reversed my logic.

Comment: you are trying to remove an item from an empty list.

Comment: `historyValues.remove(0);` fails if your `ArrayList` is empty. No magic behind that. *"How is the empty array getting past the size() checks?"* It doesn't, it is in the `else` branch, that means it _failed_ the size check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your comparison is inverted.

```
if(historyLabels.size() >= 1 && historyValues.size() >= 1 ){
```

should be

```
if(historyLabels.size() < 1 && historyValues.size() < 1 ){
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks- I feel sufficiently stupid for not seeing it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

`if(historyLabels.size() >= 1 && historyValues.size() >= 1 )` ==> an empty collection will have size 0 and therefore NOT match >= 1. This is why it goes to the `else` where you try to remove the first element of an empty collection.

Answer (score 0):

`historyValues.remove(0);`

You're removing the first element, but you have no elements if you're in the else clause (because `>= 1` failed, meaning the list is empty).

Answer (score 0):

If greater than 1 else remove index.

So in the else case it's possible for the size to be 0, and the arraylist empty